# How to disable hostBuilder:reloadConfigOnChange in code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Despite I use `WebApplication.CreateBuilder` (not `Default`), and I clear configuration sources, and I use customized source with explicit reload on change set to false, the default from `HostApplicationBuilder` still kicks in and as effect I get reload on change enabled (because it is default behavior).

[Microsoft describes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-8.0) how to switch this flag using either command line arguments or via setting environment variable.

I am not fan of it (and the feature altogether) thus my question -- how to set hostBuilder:reloadConfigOnChange to false programmatically or even better, how to build `WebApplication` so the default configuration won't be added automatically?

*I tried a little hack, right at the start of the program I added:*

```
args = args.Concat(["hostBuilder__reloadConfigOnChange", "false"]).ToArray();
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

*also with a version with ":" instead of "__", but it didn't help.*

*Currently I am running my app via `WebApplicationFactory` (as part of the tests).*

Comment: How do you specify the JSON source? There's a [special AddJson overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.jsonconfigurationextensions.addjsonfile?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0#microsoft-extensions-configuration-jsonconfigurationextensions-addjsonfile(microsoft-extensions-configuration-iconfigurationbuilder-system-string-system-boolean-system-boolean)) that allows disabling `reloadOnChange`. Please post your code

Comment: The CLI argument and the environment variables aren't what you tried either. The CLI argument should be `hostBuilder:reloadConfigOnChange` while the env variable should be `DOTNET_hostBuilder:reloadConfigOnChange`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I don't follow. I don't specify JSON source, that is the point, it is done automatically. And I didn't try CLI or env, because I want to disable it via code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting it via the `Environment` class?

Add the following line of code before the creation of the `WebApplication.CreateBuilders()`
`Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_hostBuilder:reloadConfigOnChange", "false");` and `using System;` if that's not being used yet!

This seems to do the trick for me.

Comment: Many thanks. I didn' think about altering environment :-). For comparison, without your change I ran 5 times a set of 100 tests (in parallel). On each try the run failed with "The configured user limit (128) on the number of inotify instances...", after change again 5 runs, no error.